# LoadControl in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-ajax

Since i havn't access to the TemplateControl or page from a WCF service i was wondering if it was possible to render a custom control?  If so how would one do it?

```
 private string GetRenderedHtmlFrom(Control control)
 {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter(stringBuilder);
        HtmlTextWriter htmlWriter  = new HtmlTextWriter(textWriter);
        control.RenderControl(htmlWriter );
        return stringBuilder.ToString();
 }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually wasn't achievable and i ended up abandoning the idea.  The rough solution i implemented was loading an html page, and using string.Format() to manipulate it then returned the results as a string and let the JavaScript 'load the control'.